# value of array gets updated on updating Property value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code in JS file

```
    var listOfCountries = [];
    var Country = {};
    Country = { "CountryCode": null, "SerialNo": 0, "FrzInd": false }

    for (var i=0; i < $('#ulCustomCountryList li').length; i++) {
      Country.CountryCode = $("#countryCode_" + i).val();
      Country.SerialNo = $("#serialNo_" + i).val();
      listOfCountries.push(Country);
    }
```

in first iteration: when countryCode_0 is "IND" then `listOfCountries[0].CountryCode = "IND"` , in second Iteration when countryCode_1 is "AUS" then `listOfCountries[1].CountryCode = "AUS"` but it alse updates the value of listOfCountries[0].CountryCode to `listOfCountries[0].CountryCode = "AUS"`

Comment: Create a new object in every iteration. At the moment you always update the same `Country` object.

Comment: put `var Country = {};Country = { "CountryCode": null, "SerialNo": 0, "FrzInd": false }` these two lines in loop so that it can take new object on every iteration.

Comment: It is not similar you have taken empty object in loop in that another code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Objects are a reference. All reference to object would be updated.
you push the same object every iteration so you have two ways to fix it

1- Create new object on every iteration
As following:

```
  var countriesCount = $('#ulCustomCountryList li').length; //- 1
  listOfCountries =[];
  for (var i = 0; i < countriesCount; i++) {

    var Country = { "CountryCode": null, "SerialNo": 0, "FrzInd": false }
    Country.CountryCode = $("#countryCode_" + i).val();
    Country.SerialNo = $("#serialNo_" + i).val();
    listOfCountries.push(Country);

  }
```

or 
2 - use `Object.assign({},Country)` for copy the object every iteration.

```
     var countriesCount = $('#ulCustomCountryList li').length; //- 1
       var listOfCountries = [];
        var Country = {};
        Country = { "CountryCode": null, "SerialNo": 0, "FrzInd": false }

        for (var i=0; i < countriesCount; i++) {
          var copy = Object.assign({}, Country);
          copy.CountryCode = $("#countryCode_" + i).val();
          copy.SerialNo = $("#serialNo_" + i).val();
          listOfCountries.push(copy);
        }
```